# JavaScript customize text from dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, html

I was having some problem when trying to dynamically add a table to HTML using JavaScript.

I got an array and my sample data is `[0,0,5,2,7,5,4,5,0]`

My HTML:

```
<div id="ftw" style="min-width:80px; overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden; display:none;">
    <table id="ft" class="table" style="font-size:13.5px">

    </table>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('ftw').style.display = 'block';
        var table = document.getElementById("ft");

        // helper function        
        function addCell(tr, text) {
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.textContent = text;
            return td;
        }
```

I wanted to do something like when the `item == 0`, then I set the font to red color. If `item > 0`, I wanted to bold the `item`.

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post attempts?

Comment: You want this https://jsfiddle.net/87jc448x/ ?

Comment: Yeah something like that. But if the item is larger than 0, I wanted to bold the number only

Comment: Check my answer @hyperfkcb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87jc448x/1/)..

I change `td.textContent` to `td.innerHTML` and add `row.style.color="red";` `addCell(row, 'Every <b>' + item + '</b> day(s)');`

```
 function addCell(tr, text) {
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.innerHTML = text;
            return td;
        }



dataset.forEach(function (item) {
            var row = table.insertRow();
            if(item == 0){
            row.style.color="red";
                addCell(row, 'No record');
            }else{  
                addCell(row, 'Every <b>' + item + '</b> day(s)');

            }
        });
```